# почему не работает метод startactivity при вызове view из presenter?

Tags: java, android, mvp

В презентере обращаюсь к базе данных и в случае успешного ответа, стартую новую активити из вью

код :

```
    mRepository.setUrl(resources.getString(R.string.url_server) + resources.getString(R.string.url_authorization));
    mRepository.setJson(getJsonQuery());
    mRepository.setRequest("post");
    mRepository.loadResponse(new ModelDB.CompleteCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(String response) {
            mView.hideProgressDialog();
            if (response.equals("successful")) {
                //авторизация пройдена успешна, перехожу к карте
                Intent intent = new Intent(mView.getContextView(), MapView.class);
                intent.putExtra("main_user", mView.getUsername());
                intent.putExtra("tittle_user", mView.getUsername());
                mView.startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                mView.showToast(response);
            }
```

код из View

```
@Override
public void startActivity(Intent intent) {
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

**mView** и **mRepository** компоненты MVP приложения.

В рантайме выходит ошибка

> 09-26 14:41:11.336 22352-22352/popovvad.findme E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: popovvad.findme, PID: 22352
>       java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
>           at popovvad.findme.authorization.AuthorizationView.startActivity(AuthorizationView.java:96)

При этом метод showToast у view работает, проблем с типами не было.
Подскажите что делаю не так?

P.S. StackOverflowError

Comment: попробуйте передавать не интент во вью, а данные (main_user и tittle_user), а там уже паковать в интент

Comment: ну вы переопределили у `Activity` метод так, что он всегда вызывает сам себя, поэтому стек кончается. Либо вызывайте метод предка через `super`, либо переименуйте в интерфейсе метод, чтобы не пришлось переопределять.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь, как уже указали в комментариях,

```
@Override
public void startActivity(Intent intent) {
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Ваш метод вызывает сам себя, из-за чего происходит `StackOverflowError`.

Лучше создать подобный метод в view:

Нужно:

```
@Override
public void startMapActivity(String mainUser, String titleUser) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapView.class);
    intent.putExtra("main_user", mainUser);
    intent.putExtra("title_user", titleUser);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

И соответственно вызов:

```
mRepository.setUrl(resources.getString(R.string.url_server) + resources.getString(R.string.url_authorization));
mRepository.setJson(getJsonQuery());
mRepository.setRequest("post");
mRepository.loadResponse(new ModelDB.CompleteCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(String response) {
        mView.hideProgressDialog();
        if (response.equals("successful")) {
            mView.startMapActivity(mView.getUsername(), mView.getUsername());
        } else {
            mView.showToast(response);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Именно так я и сделал, спасибо